# How to fix "Out of Memory" in dynamic arrays in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

I am trying to build a dynamic array in c++ like this:

```
int **matrix = 0;    
matrix = new int * [dim];
for (int i = 0; i < dim; i++)
    matrix[i] = new int[dim];
```

when "dim" exceed s from 90000, program crashes and gives me out of memory (it exceeds 2 GB of RAM)

any idea how to fix it? any other solution please?

Comment: You should accept some of your previous questions.

Comment: If the matrix is not dense there are ways of representing it that don't use lots of memory. Are you sure you need all that memory?

Answer (score 3):

To allocate more than 2 GB of memory, you will need to compile your program for, and run it on, a 64-bit operating system.

Comment: There is not any other choice ?

Comment: Some 32-bit operating systems have a way to squeeze a small amount of additional application memory, perhaps up to 3 GB. However, this is operating system dependent and usually must be selected as an OS boot option.

Comment: @Bipario , or write them to disk and page them in/out of memory when needed, or play with assembly and do PAE.

Comment: Could you please explain more how to write it to disk?

Comment: @Greg - The server versions of windows allow for 4GB with the /3GB option.

Comment: 32-bit Windows lets you allocate up to 16TB of storage. The catch is that you have to basically [write your own memory manager](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/08/10/211890.aspx) so that you repeatedly map and unmap parts of that storage into your process's 2GB or 3GB window.

Comment: Yeah, that's no fun at all (I remember [EMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expanded_memory)). Why not use a 64-bit OS? They're everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the /3GB switch, which should give you an extra 1GB on the consumer (ie: non-server) versions of 32 bit windows.

[Details of /3GB switch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff556232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks but it does not solve my problem, because I may exceed 3 GB too. I should find another way to build this matrix. but how ?! :(

Comment: @Bipario - Uhhh...not in memory.

Comment: so where ? any suggestion ?  I need to build this matrix then I want to fill it with integers !

Comment: @Bipario - What problem are you actually trying to solve. Not the memory issue, but the actual problem. Is this homework? Accept some of your other answers also.

Comment: No this is not a home work. This is part of a project where I need to build a very big matrix and fill the cells with integers.

Comment: @Bipario - Why? Assume I reject the assumption that you _need_ a big matrix. Explain the problem.

Comment: Ummm.. it is hard to explain it. I need to create a function that builds a dynamic array matrix. Then I need to fill this matrix by the help of other functions. In other words, I need to fill the matrix by integers and then see which cell has a specified integer.

Comment: @Bipario - Where is the data coming from? A calculation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9570/discussion-between-ritch-melton-and-bipario)